# ValueError: time data '1/1/17 0:03' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

I want to convert the time in csv file to a datetime object in Python so that I can calculate the time difference. But I am keeping get error when I do that.

My codes were:
`import datetime
from time import strptime
a=datetime.strptime('1/1/17 0:03', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
b=datetime.strptime('1/31/17 9:57', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')`

I have tried both dates and times and I am keeping getting the value error as followed:

```
b=datetime.strptime('1/31/17 9:57', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')

Traceback (most recent call last):   
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/_strptime.py", line 565, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/_strptime.py", line 362, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))

ValueError: time data '1/31/17 9:57' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: for python codes, edit with proper indentation please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)! it looks like both the day and month should be zero padded (01, 02, ...31) and for the year, you should use %y (lower case).The time should also be zero padded (00:03).

Comment: %y  works. Thanks. But when I used the zero padded %-m, %-d, %-H and %-M it returns another error such as ValueError: '-' is a bad directive in format '%-m/%-d/%y %-H:%-M'. Do you know why?

Comment: dont add "-", you should run it like this:
    strptime('01/31/17 09:57', '%m/%d/%y %H:%M')

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some research on the different formatting variables with datetime.strptime().  For '%m' that is for the month, but padded with a zero.  You can read-up on the strptime reference [on this site here](http://strftime.org/).

```
from datetime import datetime
from time import strptime

a=datetime.strptime('01/01/2017 00:03', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
```

Comment: I tried the one with %-m as well. It gave me another error :ValueError: '-' is a bad directive in format '%-m/%-d/%Y %-H:%-M' is that the corret way?